# MergeSort with Dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a function mergeSort that returns a dynamic array of type intervalo_t. As it is, the function is working nicely, the problem I have is that when I run Valgrind to check for memory loss, turns out I'm loosing quite a bit.

Intervalo_t definition:

```
struct intervalo_t {
    nat inicio;
    nat fin;
};
```

This is the code:

```
intervalo_t* mergeSort(intervalo_t *intervalos, nat n)
{   
    intervalo_t* ret=new intervalo_t[n];
    if(n==2){
        if (intervalos[0].fin>intervalos[1].fin){
            ret[0]=intervalos[1];
            ret[1]=intervalos[0];
        }else{
            ret[0]=intervalos[0];
            ret[1]=intervalos[1];
        }
    //caso base
    }else if (n==1){
        ret[0]=intervalos[0];
    //caso base
    }else{
        nat k=0;        
        if((n%2)!=0){
            k=1;
        }//Si es par o no
        intervalo_t* interA =new intervalo_t[n/2 + k];
        intervalo_t* interB =new intervalo_t[n/2];
        for (nat i=0; i<n/2; i++){
            interA[i]=intervalos[i];
            interB[i]=intervalos[i+(n/2)];
        }//for
        if (k==1){ 
            interA[(n/2)]=intervalos[n-1];
        }
        interA=mergeSort(interA, n/2 + k);
        interB=mergeSort(interB, n/2);
        nat i=0;
        nat j=0;
        nat r=0;
        while((i<((n/2)+k)) && (j<(n/2))){
            if (interA[i].fin>interB[j].fin){
                ret[r]=interB[j];
                j++;
            }else{
                ret[r]=interA[i];
                i++;
            }
            r++;
        }
        while(i<(n/2)+k){
            ret[r]=interA[i];
            i++;
            r++;
        }
        while(j<(n/2)){
            ret[r]=interA[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        delete[] interA;
        delete[] interB;
    //recursion
    }
    return ret; 
}
```

And this is Valgrind's output:

```
==15556== 
==15556== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15556==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 2 blocks
==15556==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 10 frees, 77,959 bytes allocated
==15556== 
==15556== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==15556==    at 0x4C2F06F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15556==    by 0x401536: mergeSort(intervalo_t*, unsigned int) (intervalos.cpp:26) 
==15556==    by 0x4017C3: max_cantidad(intervalo_t*, unsigned int) (intervalos.cpp:67)
==15556==    by 0x401130: main (principal.cpp:170)
==15556== 
==15556== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==15556==    at 0x4C2F06F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15556==    by 0x401509: mergeSort(intervalo_t*, unsigned int) (intervalos.cpp:25)
==15556==    by 0x4017C3: max_cantidad(intervalo_t*, unsigned int) (intervalos.cpp:67)
==15556==    by 0x401130: main (principal.cpp:170)
==15556== 
==15556== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15556==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 2 blocks
==15556==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15556==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15556==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15556==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15556== 
==15556== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==15556== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I ran valgrind with:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./myFile <test.in
```

Test.in:

```
mergeSort
15
30
45
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *As it is, the function is working nicely,* -- No it is not working nicely.  Otherwise there would be no errors to report.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. It sounds like result of your function is never cleaned up but it's not possible to tell without seeing the context in which it's used.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector` instead of allocating arrays. It avoids all of these problems.

Comment: `intervalo_t* interA =new intervalo_t[n/2 + k];` -- Then you do this in the same function --  `interA=mergeSort(interA, n/2 + k);`-- This is very hard-to-maintain code, and is begging for memory leaks, double deletion errors, etc.  Your best bet is to create a dynamic array *class* that handles the memory correctly, and just use it in place of `std::vector` if you can't use `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used the last suggestion and redefined the function as a void so that I wouldn't have to do: `interA=mergeSort(interA, n/2+k);` that solved my problem without the need of creating the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the memory you allocated here:

```
intervalo_t* interA =new intervalo_t[n/2 + k];
intervalo_t* interB =new intervalo_t[n/2];
```

leaks when you overwrite those pointers here:

```
interA=mergeSort(interA, n/2 + k);
interB=mergeSort(interB, n/2);
```

It is rarely a good idea to reuse variables for multiple purposes, so use separate variables for the recursive results:

```
intervalo_t* resultA=mergeSort(interA, n/2 + k);
intervalo_t* resultB=mergeSort(interB, n/2);
```

and then use those for merging (and remember to release them).
I would also recommend disposing of the inputs immediately after recursing so you don't forget it.

Or, you could use `std::vector` and save yourself some headaches.